# Change some of cell's text's color: inconsistent macro behaviour

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a textbook made using Excel (let's not discuss the demerits of using Excel for this, I'm well aware of them), and I have a list of sentences with only one word highlighted – i.e., in a different color. For some reason, some of the non-highlighted words ended up being black (#000) and others dark gray (#333). To fix this, and since we have literally more than 1000 sentences, I tried to make a macro. Some googling led me to the following code:

```
Sub FixG2Colors()
'
'
   Dim xOut As String
   Dim xValue As String
   Dim i As Long
   Dim LastRow As Long

   LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

   Do Until ActiveCell.Row > LastRow

   xValue = ActiveCell.Text

   For i = 1 To Len(xValue)
       If (Not ActiveCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(153, 102, 255)) Then
           ActiveCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbBlack
       End If
   Next

   ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Select

   Loop

End Sub
```

So, I'm going through each character and comparing its color with the highlight color; if different, set it to black. These sentences are every 4th row, so I'm running it the loop from the first selected cell to the end of the sheet.

My problem is that I'm getting wildly inconsistent behaviour. Removing the loop and running the loop works correctly… most of the time. In some cases, the cell content is effectively modified. For example:

```
Actually, I was hoping / you could help me / with this problem.
```

Has "Actually" highlighted. Running the macro not only removes the highlight (which I double and triple-checked: it's RGB(153, 102, 255)), it also **changes the font** at seemingly random sections of the sentence. I open the file, run the macro; close the file without saving and open it again; run the macro on the same sentence, and the font will change at different sections from before.

Also, it works properly on other sentences.

When I try to run the loop, it takes much longer than it should, Excel usually crashes (even though it has run successfully at least once), the results are inconsistent even for the same cell on different runs…

I tried this on macOS with the latest Excel and OS, on a Windows VM, on a couple of Windows machines… the only thing consistent is how inconsistent this is.

So my question is two-fold:
1- Are macros / is VBA really this unreliable / inconsistent?
2- Is there a better way to implement this functionality?

Comment: In my 2 years experience with VBA, I have never encountered inconsistencies you describe. However I see nothing wrong with the code. Is there any other code in the workbook? Any events? How are you calling/running the Sub? Have you tried stepping the procedure via F8 to see what is actually going on?

Comment: What columns do you have your text in?

Comment: @SpringFilip Like I said, this is my first VBA macro so I'm doing it like a Neanderthal: alt-F11 to open the editor, create a new module, paste the text above there, and click the "Run macro" button on the editor. The editor only shows Microsoft Excel Objects and the module I did, so as far as I can tell there's no other code nor events. I've never tried stopping the procedure; I'll give it a try.

Comment: @GMalc the text is on column C, and I run this macro with a cell from column C selected.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish in this line `Do Until ActiveCell.Row > LastRow`; if `LastRow` is a number "more then 1000", then if your `ActiveCell.Row` is `C1`, how can it be `>` 1000? You need to loop through each row; e.g. `For x = 1 to LastRow`

Answer (score 0):

Per my comments; I would loop through to the last row, this code was tested on a small example with multiple colored characters...(based on code by @Gary'sStudent)

```
Sub fixFontColor()
    Dim r As Long, x As Integer, lRow As Long
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        For r = 1 To lRow 'Number of rows

            For x = 1 To Len(Cells(r, 3).Value) 'for each character in cell

                If Cells(r, 3).Characters(Start:=x, Length:=1).Font.Color <> RGB(153, 102, 255) Then
                    Cells(r, 3).Characters(Start:=x, Length:=1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End If

            Next x

        Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't ActiveCell.Row an integer that matches the current cell row? I've tested it with `MsgBox ActiveCell.Row` and it's returning, for example, 366 rather than C366, making a comparison `366 > 1000` possible. 
Also, I want to edit every 4th row (the others contain data I don't want to change), and the last row of the sheet might be skipped; something like: `current row is 998; fix; skip 4 rows; current row is 1002; is it bigger than 1000? Yes, so break`.

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear, i don't like using a `Do Until` when using a last row variable.  If you tested my code, did you get inconsistent results?

Comment: I tried it a couple of times, and either Excel crashed or it made 90% of the rows fully black, highlighted word included. And then Excel crashed. My tests were far from conclusive, though, and on the Mac version, so when I have time I'll try it on Windows and on smaller sheets to see how it goes and I'll let you know.

Comment: Yea, it will not work on the Mac, I did not know you were using a Mac. For the future, please identify the system you are using. Sorry I don't own a Mac and I'm not familiar with the differences when coding vba for a Mac. So, I guess that this has been mostly futile. I did test the code on a PC with MS Office 2016 and it worked.

Comment: I did mention on my main post that the inconsistencies I was having happened both on macOS, on Windows inside a VM, and on two separate Windows machines. So the issue with my initial code is not platform-specific; I'll check if yours is as well tomorrow.